# YAML file formatting in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using VSCODE and faced with an annoyance every time I paste in YAML code in an existing YML file. 
Basically the editor seems to auto format the document and in doing so messes up the significant spaces in the document. This causes builds in Azure Devops to break.
Although VS code formats the document nicely into collapsible regions, the formatting annoyance makes it hard to use.
Any help would be appreciated.

BEFORE:

[image: BEFORE]

---

AFTER:
[image]

Answer (score 30):

I fixed this by changing `editor.autoIndent` settings for `yaml` and `dockercompose` language

**Update:** In VsCode, press `ctrl+shift+p` (`cmd+shift+p` in Mac), and search for `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` to add the following configuration:

```json
"[yaml]": {
  "editor.autoIndent": "advanced"
},
"[dockercompose]": {
  "editor.autoIndent": "advanced"
}
```

Comment: Point I'd add, modify the vscode `settings.json`  `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`  file as in suggestion made by @tal-kohavy

Comment: For GitHub Actions users add the setting to `"[github-actions-workflow]"` as well.

Comment: @xab feel free to edit the answer

Answer (score 22):

In VsCode, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on Windows (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in Mac), and search for `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`. There, I added this line:

```json
"[yaml]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-yaml"
},
```

I picked it because it contained the word `yaml`, so I figured it must be yaml specific.
Anyhow, it seems to do a pretty good job for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is in the first line. Maybe when you copy the code, you're not copying the indentation on the first line.
One trick I use, is copying from the end of the preceding line, so the copied code starts with a newline, and then the paste is perfect.

Or just add the indentation on that first line, after pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the setting `format on paste`.   This is a global setting, but plugins sometimes have their own, so if you're running a formatter like prettier, you'll need to see whether this is even an option with that plugin.

Comment: The global setting is off, I have prettier installed and it doesn't seem to have any setting for this. Disabling Prettier didn't change the behavior

Answer (score 1):

VSCode has a command to "Save without Formatting".

I noticed that my indentation changes were altered when I saved the YAML file. However, if I press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> in Mac, and type Save without formatting, and click that command to save, my indentations are preserved.

For Mac, the same command can also be executed with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

Try onlineyamltools.com

It's like the Swiss Army Knife for YAML and it's free to use.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion). also, this doesn't really answer the question as asked...